# Java META-INF/services

Tags: java, meta-inf

What is the purpose of META-INF/services in Java ?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70216/2987755

Answer (score 28):

It's intended to store service provider configuration files.

A Service provider is an implementation of a Service Provider Interface packaged as JAR.

A Service loader discover and load all implementations declared in the service provider configuration file.

A configuration file is a file named as the fully qualified name of the interface and its content is a list of fully qualified names of implementations.

Following is an example of provider configuration file for  javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer that is used by Servlet 3.0 at webapp startup.

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer
org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer
```

In this example

- Tomcat is the Service Loader;
- javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer is the Service Provider Interface
- file named javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer is the Service Provider configuration file;
- org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer and org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer are Service providers

When tomcat startup webapp call both

```
onStartup(java.util.Set<java.lang.Class<?>> types, ServletContext context)
```

methods on JasperInitializer and SpringServletContainerInitializer classes

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at the [`ServiceLoader` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Before Java 9, [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) find the implementations for a Service from the file in META-INF/services which has fully qualified name same as the Service interface. It contain list of fully qualified names of the implementations.

From Java 9 It have modules and modules have module descriptors.
Those 'module' can define the services and their implementation that a ServiceLoader could load.

Comment: I think this is wrong. META-INF does not contain modules? Can you point to an example where they do?