# Apache Tika parser not working in fat jar

Tags: java, apache-tika

I create empty maven app, then add dependencies

```
tika-core
tika-parsers-standard-package
slf4j-api 
slf4j-simple
```

and **maven-assembly-plugin** to make a fat jar.

resulting 47M file has 102 lines of `mvn dependency:tree`
Everything looks OK, but while running this troubleshooting snippet

```
Tika tika = new Tika();

CompositeParser parser = (CompositeParser)tika.getParser();

for (MediaType type : parser.getSupportedTypes(new ParseContext())) {
    String typeStr = type.toString();
    System.out.println(++cnt + " " + typeStr);
}
```

tika reports only two supported mimetypes

```
video/mpeg
video/x-msvideo
```

I see not a single warning from

```
java -jar target/smallTika-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Dorg.apache.tika.service.error.warn=true
```

I've tried a lot with configs, versions, switching to maven shade plugin and so on

Funny thing: if I run the app from IDE it reports 229 mimetypes and works like a charm.

Also, if I create empty springboot app and add

```
tika-core
tika-parsers-standard-package
```

deps, this diagnostic snippet also works fine (as standard spring jar).

**SOLUTION (Gagravarr's comment):**

switch to **maven-shade-plugin** plugin and add transformer

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the `META-INF` services files - they need to be appended not "last one wins"

Comment: Huge thanks, @Gagravarr ! Will you write an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: Only a subisidiary problem, but `-Dsysprop` arguments must be BEFORE (to the LEFT of) the jarfile argument, not after (to the right). If you treat `-jar jarfile` as a unit, which many do but is not required, `-D` must be before `-jar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Tika makes use of [`META-INF/services`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544899/java-meta-inf-services) files to allow runtime discovery of available classes for things like Detection and Parsers

When building a shaded / fat jar, you need to take care with these services files. They are plain text files, one class name per line. You want to append them all together, and not take just the first or last one (which is often the default with shading tools)