# Accessing resources from webapp folder using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with the following structure:

src

|--main

---|--java

---|--resources

------|--templates

------|--application.properties

---|--webapp

------|--resources

---------|--static

------------|--css

------------|--img

---------------|--logo.jpg

------------|--js

------------|--favicon.ico

------|--WEB-INF

---------|--view

------------|--index.jsp

In my MvcConfig, I have added ResourceHandler as below

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

In my JSPs, I can access the images from img folder using

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/static/img/logo.jpg" />">
```

Trying to access the same image in a class,
I tried the following code:

```
ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("logo.jpg");
```

and also tried using many variations for the image path.
However, every time I receive a false value for cpr.exists()

Surprisingly, I received true when I changed the parameter to favicon.ico.

What am I doing wrong? Please explain this behaviour and also explain what is the right way to access the resource.

Comment: did you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15796409/3892213

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this and it worked. new ClassPathResource("../../resources/static/img/logo.jpg"); However, I am not sure if it is the right way to use double dots to access the resource.