# JSF 2.0 app does not find resource

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, glassfish

I am new to developing on JSF (and new to web development in general) and I am trying to put an image on a page. 
I'm developing my JSF app in Eclipse and running it on Glassfish 3.1.2. I have registered Glassfish as a server in Eclipse, and running the app via Eclipse.

I use the following markup on my xhtml page:

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="logo.png"/>
```

I copied the image in META-INF/resources/images/logo.png .
The image does not appear on the page and when I view the page source I see the element

```
<img src="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
```

indicating that the image is not found.

When I export my app to a war file and deploy it onto Glassfish via the autodeploy folder, I get the same results - the page displays, but the image does not appear.

Can anyone advise why the image resource is not found?

Comment: Have you tried to put resource directory in root folder of project.? it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I copied the image in META-INF/resources/images/logo.png*

This location will only work if the project represents a standalone module JAR which ultimately ends up in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the WAR.

This does not seem to the case in your particular case. Nothing in your question indicates that you're indeed developing a module JAR file. Apparently you've placed it straight in the WAR this way. This is not right.

You need to put the `/resources` folder straight in the public web content, not in the `META-INF` folder.

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- faces-config.xml
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- resources
 |    `-- images
 |         `-- logo.png
 `-- index.xhtml
```

#### See also:

- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738)
- [Why some resource files are put under META-INF directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609272/why-some-resource-files-are-put-under-meta-inf-directory/5609325#5609325)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using `images` as library name does not look entirely right. Just use

```html
<h:graphicImage name="images/logo.png"/>
```

#### See also:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks for your help!