# What are files located in *.jar/META-INF/*.*?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, meta-inf

I found that `c.tld` file of `jstl-1.2.jar` is located in `META-INF/*.*` inside this jar. How to access these files from code in this jar? Just with `getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/c.tld")`? Or META-INF has special processing rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to get the content of the `c.tld` using `getResourceAsStream`. Just do not change it and write back to the file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253/32090

Answer (score 0):

tld files are related to **Tag libraries**. These files will specify when you use a tag in JSP, which class to be executed and which method to be executed. You can access TLDs using URI attribute of **taglib** directive in JSP.

JSTL tutorial on how to use these tag libraries is available at : http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/introduction.shtml