# Standard Config File Location for a Java Library?

Tags: java, configuration, resourcebundle, properties-file

For my current project ([Better Checks - a small argument validation library](http://better-checks.trick17.ch/)), I am trying to figure out where (in the classpath) the applications using the library should put the configuration file. It is a .properties file with customized error message formats.

Is there a standard or de facto standard location for library config files?

My current take is `/better-checks.properties`. I am a bit worried that this is not a good idea, since it is directly in the root of the classpath and might *theoretically* collide with some other file.

An alternative would be to put it into the root package of the library, `/ch/trick17/betterchecks/config.properties` which would prevent name collisions but seems a bit weird.

**Edit:** Take into account that if I want to support internationalization by using resource bundles, applications might end up with many `better-checks_*.properties` in the classpath root. This is not very nice, is it?

Comment: How about `/config/config.properties` ? (a.k.a. a `config` folder).

Answer (score 0):

You're worried about a problem that is unlikely.  I agree - it is weird.  As long as it's in the CLASSPATH you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Majority of the applications choose putting config files in the classpath as you have done.

Some of the frameworks put some of their config file inside META-INF directory.
For e.g., EJB3 persistence config file defaults to META-INF/persistence.xml

However its debatable whether this is a good practise or not. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216/whats-the-purpose-of-meta-inf) for a good discussion and decide for yourself.