# Runnable JAR file doesn't run after export in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I have the following hierarchy :

[image]

When I export the project into a runnable JAR file (32 bit platform) , the file 
is created successfully , but when I try to run it , nothing happens - no response from the OS (windows 7 pro) .

Why can't I run the jar file ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
C:\1>java -jar ex3.jar
Catched FileNotFoundException: C:\1\ex3-natives-windows-i586.jar (The system can
not find the file specified), while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of jar:fil
e:/C:/1/ex3-natives-windows-i586.jar!/ (file:/C:/1/ + ex3-natives-windows-i586.j
ar)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluege
n-rt in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoad
erBase.java:442)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.ja
va:59)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNIL
ibLoaderBase.java:90)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.j
ava:328)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrar
y(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.loadGlueGenRTImpl(Platform.java:251)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.access$000(Platform.java:57)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:186)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:183)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:183)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.<init>(GLCanvas.java:246)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.<init>(GLCanvas.java:196)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.<init>(GLCanvas.java:186)
        at WorldController.<init>(WorldController.java:119)
        at WorldController$1.run(WorldController.java:478)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

C:\1>
```

**Updated :**

```
C:\>
C:\>java -jar ex3.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.j
dt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class WorldC
ontroller with modifiers "public static"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)

C:\>
```

Comment: Run the jar in command prompt using `java -jar <jar file name>` and check any exceptions are there.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: I added it to the post ,there are exceptions , but the files that are supposedly missing are there .

Comment: When you export runnable jar in eclipse use "Package required libraies  into JAR" then try.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: Same as before , the output is attached .

Comment: There is no main methid in your class.

Comment: can you show us the class you are trying to execute? and also the metainf* file?

*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216/whats-the-purpose-of-meta-inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you got a illegal call. That means you try to call a method wich you're not allowed to call. (referenced to your updated edit)

Your error says that you want to execute a method with the modifiers public static. A static method must be calls with the class name not with the object:

```
SomeClass.staticMethodCall();
```

The following would be wrong:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.staticMethodCall();
```