# Location of Spring Application Context Files

Tags: spring, spring-batch, applicationcontext

I've always placed my application context files in src/main/resources.  But I'm starting to learn Spring Batch and when I download the template, I noticed that their application context files are in META-INF.

Should I be using META-INF?  From [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216/whats-the-purpose-of-meta-inf) I've read it seems that META-INF should only be used by the compiler.  But when I expand all of the Spring Maven dependencies I have, all of the context files are in META-INF.

So what's the difference?  Why are some context files in META-INF and others aren't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

META-INF is starting to be used by more and more frameworks as the 'common' place to put non-Java configuration files (properties, xmls, etc.)  For example, Servlet 3.0 web-fragment specifies the xml component should be in the META-INF folder, as well as JPA describing persistence.xml in META-INF.

Springs use of META-INF as the component place is in keeping with these frameworks.

but, of course, it's all up to the developer/project

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's difficult to keep up with the best practices.