# How to find Spring beans.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection, ear

I've got an EAR with JAR and WAR, and a beans.xml with my Spring  definitions.  I'm using Maven to build this project.  Code within the JAR is trying to find the beans.xml, but it doesn't find it.

Do I want beans.xml in:

EAR's META-INF/beans.xml?
or
JAR's META-INF/beans.xml?

I've tried the following things:

*Failure 1: JAR's META-INF/beans.xml*

```
 String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "META-INF/beans.xml";

 ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_FILE_NAME);
 BeanFactory factory = context;
```

This gives:

BeansDeployer deploy org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansException: Unable to read root element of the given input stream.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

*Failure 2: EAR's META-INF/beans.xml*

```
 String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "classpath*:/META-INF/*beans.xml";

 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_FILE_NAME);
 BeanFactory factory = context;
```

This gives FileNotFoundException, because maven-ear-plugin only copies application.xml but doesn't include beans.xml when EAR'ing the application.  If this is the correct method, is there any way to make Maven include beans.xml when it builds?

Or should it be elsewhere, entirely?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253/61624), "Generally speaking, you should not put anything into META-INF yourself."  Why are you assuming it should be inside META-INF?

But, if you want it copied into your ear's META-INF folder, put it under your `ejb/src/main/resources/META-INF` directory.  You may have to create some of those manually.