# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

When I build my app, I get the following error:

> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cn.sz.cyrus.kotlintest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions{
            annotationProcessorOptions{
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        /*     
          exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
          exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
          exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
          exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        */
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
    compile 'ai.api:libai:1.4.8'
    compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.5@aar'
    // api.ai SDK dependencies
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

When I add this code to my build.gradle file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

This error would be solved, but another problem will happen. Like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.HeapAnalyzerService
at com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(LeakCanary.java:145)
at cn.sz.cyrus.wemz.TestApplication.onCreate(TestApplication.kt:32)
```

Who has ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I faced the same issue when accessing Google API Client Library for Android.
Solved the issue by excluding the module HttpClient from gradle dependencies.

Refer Google docs for more details
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup 
search the docs page with "On Android, you will need to explicitly exclude unused dependencies:"

Comment: Try change minimum Android version >= 21 in your build.gradle android{}

Answer (score 916, accepted):

You can add this in `yourProject/app/build.gradle` inside `android{}`. The [exclude](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions) function adds the named resource to the list of resources that are not packaged in the APK.

```
android {      
      packagingOptions {
        exclude("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/license.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/NOTICE")
        exclude("META-INF/NOTICE.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/notice.txt")
        exclude("META-INF/ASL2.0")
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") 
      }          
}
```

The `exclude` function is deprecated in 7.0.2 and you should use something similar to this:

```
android {
   ...
   packagingOptions {
       resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this works and what the meaning of "META-INF" is? Thank you!

Comment: @CodeSlave   it causes some problem with apk if we didn't exclude theses files                                                                             from https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html                        Exclude
    Paths that match an exclude pattern will not be included in the APK. that all i know . i have not complete idea about this problem

Comment: Can you tell a bit about this? I tried and it worked but my error said it discover two 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'. As I'm packaging this file as well, it should have given me error again, right?

Comment: Adding this to my projects leads to many other errors, what can be done now?

Comment: @KumarGaurav i  didn't get it

Comment: @ShaabanEbrahim I have found the solution for this problem in my app. Explicit  jar dependency was the issue. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965839/1199154

Comment: @Shaaban Ebrahim : I've been sitting with the Google API for a couple of weeks now, why does this cause an issue now? What are these things for anyhow?

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: In my case I also needed to add 'META-INF/LICENSE.md' and 'META-INF/LICENSE-notice.md'

Comment: I just updated the androidx core libraries in my app's build.gradle and it solved the problem.
1. androidx.core:core:
2. androidx.core:core-ktx:

Comment: Add exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") in packaginOptions list

Comment: this answer is correct. if in a project someone has more modules like library projects, this  packagingOptions {} should be in app/ Gradle ,exactly in android tags.

Comment: To me, the reason was adding this into build.gradle(app) so I deleted, then everything is fine now: implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.6'

Comment: @ShaabanEbrahim This is not and explanation: " it causes some problem with apk if we didn't exclude theses files from google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/… Exclude Paths that match an exclude pattern will not be included in the APK. that all i know . i have not complete idea about this problem"

Comment: Does not work for me, I don't see how these exclusions refer to '2 files found with path 'win32-x86-64/attach_hotspot_windows.dll'.  I'm compiling android where the heck is this coming from and I'm on a MAC
'

Comment: What's the purpose of META-INF? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216/whats-the-purpose-of-meta-inf

Comment: I had just added this
 implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', name: 'httpclient5', version: '5.2.1'
into build.gradle. Did not need it. Removed it. Problem solved.

Comment: Read the error properly. I updated the plugins which caused an error and the error gone. :)

Comment: packagingOptions is now deprecated, suggest renaming to packaging

Answer (score 219):

In my case it was enough to exclude only path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' on `yourProject/app/build.gradle` inside `android{}`  . Here it is

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
```

And then do Clean Project and Rebuild Project.

Comment: @SilSur exclude that file which so you in error like in my code same error for "META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro" this file, and then I was add 
exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro' and its work.

Comment: You don't need to clean just sync gradle files

Comment: Thanks! Helped when I added `exclude 'DebugProbesKt.bin'` into `packagingOptions`.

Comment: So why is it happening in the first place?

Answer (score 110):

The solutions here didn't help me, but [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Android-ndk/vfMfld5FY7A) did.

If you have a library that's adding some android .so files –like `libassmidi.so` or `libgnustl_shared.so`– you have to tell **gradle** to pick just one when packaging, otherwise you'll get the conflict.

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libassmidi.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libassmidi.so'
  }
}
```

I was having this issue when using a React Native app as a library in an Android project.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem with only one .so file. There is another file called gdbserver in the same folder and after adding the packagingOptions for the library it works now.

Comment: Thank you! Helped when I had a JNA aar as nested dependency

Comment: thanks! In my case I added such line `pickFirst "**/libarcore_sdk_c.so"`, works well

Answer (score 50):

Basically when gradle puts together the apk file, it copies content from all the compile dependencies, It is intelligent enough to see that there is a duplicate file..coming from two different jar files. This could be any file like a.txt or META-INF/DEPENDENCIES. It might be best to exclude these files using the below, in case the file is present there only for informational purposes.

```
android{
    packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
```

Or if in case, the file is a mandatory file like a class file, that has been duplicated across two jar dependencies that are related to each other, it is best to find alternatives to these jars, in the way of a more compatible version.

Comment: When i add this to my project, i get another error which again i am not able to resolve! Any other solution?

Comment: In my case this dependency was causing the problem : implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev20210120-1.31.0'

Answer (score 40):

I have faced a similar issue working in a multiple modules app environment:

> Error: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. More than one file
>   was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/AL2.0'

This issue was being reported by several of these modules of mine and none of the above solutions were fixing it.
Turns out, I was using version Coroutines 1.3.6 which seemed to be embedding META-INF/AL2.0 which was already embedded by another of the libraries I was using. To fix it, I have added the following code snippet to the build.gradle of the module that was failing:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlinx", module: "kotlinx-coroutines-debug"

    }
}
```

Given that it was happening on multiple modules, I have moved that `resolutionStrategy` code to my project level build.gradle.
Everything worked after that.

Comment: + for explanation, which helped me diagnose issue I was facing

Answer (score 37):

Had similar message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   More than one file was found with OS independent path 'constant-values.html'

To resolve it, I had to enable packages view(**1**) in Android Studio, then browse through the tree to libraries, and locate the duplicates(**2**)

Then, ctrl+alt+f12 (or RMB menu)(**3**) - and found libraries which caused the issue. 
Made list of files inside those libs which caused the issues, and wrote them to app's build.gradle file inside **android** section. Other option is to deal with the library, containing duplicate files

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
    exclude 'allclasses-noframe.html'
    <..>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you "then browse through the tree to libraries, and locate the duplicates" ? Did you really go over all of the files in all folders?

Comment: I'm also confused about "locate the duplicates."  There are maybe 100 subentries in app/Libraries... how does one go about locating duplicates?

Comment: In my case, I had to add a wild card to the path in order to exclude the file in the subfolder. e.g "\*\*/file_to_exclude.dll". I also exclude a folder and its children with "folder_content_to_exclude/\*\*"

Answer (score 37):

It's perfectly safe to exclude all meta-info files which are there just for documentation and information purposes:

```
android{
    packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101232/13093413

Answer (score 29):

For Gradle 7.2 and later
Add in-app Gradle file

```
android {
  
   packagingOptions {
       resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
   }


}
```

Answer (score 26):

Add the following in app level gradle file inside android{}

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") 
}
```

Answer (score 25):

This happens when using

org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.0

And is fixed in next version

org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1

Comment: similar issue with  org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.6 which is the lastest as of now. had to downgrade

Comment: Yeah, same issue on 1.3.6

Comment: I had to downgrade from 1.3.9 to 1.2.1 for org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test

Answer (score 21):

I was having the same problem and I tried this

> Error: More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'

**Solution:** 
All you have to do to fix this is to add this to the android { } section in your app's 'build.gradle'

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I has encountered the same error, and I found that it resulted from **different modules contained the same classes from different packages**.

e.g. One used androidx package, and the other used pre-androidx

I solved it by migrating the pre-androidx module to androidx using built-in feature of Android Studio: **"Refactor --> Migrate to Androidx..."** without excluding anything.

---

For your situation, you may check if you have any dependency mismatches among modules.

Comment: Don't forget to make a **backup** of the current version of your project since migrating to AndroidX may break your project!

Answer (score 15):

I have read all the answers related to getting this message in `Android Studio`:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'META-INF/LICENSE'

but in this case excluding classes is no neccessary, we only need to exclude `'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'`, this can be done inside the `/app/build.gradle`:

```
android{
    ...
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

}
```

Comment: This same has been told in hundreds of other answers on SO

Answer (score 13):

Based on the answers provided by @JohnnyLambada and @Shaaban Ebrahim

For excluding nested files, I used the following.

```
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/**/*")
    }
```

PS: Not spamming with same answer, but just a suggestion if you get an error something like

```sh
4 files found with path 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'.
```

which catches errors from nested directories and FYI I had setup my dependencies using `kotlin-dsl`

Answer (score 10):

I my app, I was adding the jar dependencies like this:

```
implementation files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
```

But I realised that they were already added because of the following first line in dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

This line adds all the jars in lib folder to app dependency.

Hence after removing the extra dependency `implementation files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')`

it is working fine.

Comment: This is helpful but not related to the answer. In the libraries, you find files meta-folders META-INF which can be similar in name and format. These cause duplicate file issue hence must be removed.

Answer (score 6):

I updated Studio from Java 7 to Java 8, and this problem occurred. Then I solved it this way:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding

**android.useAndroidX=true**

**android.enableJetifier=true**

to **gradle.properties** worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

This work for me

```
packagingOptions {
   exclude 'META-INF/*'
}
```

Comment: simple solution but this took my 3 hours

Comment: In my case the app worked fine until I added Firebase Cloud Messaging. This answer helped me. Took me 2hrs though. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This error is caused by adding a support library instead of AndroidX.
Make sure you use which one:

for AndroidX:

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'
}
```

If you aren't using AndroidX:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Also in manifest use the application class name instead of "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in the application tag(my application class name is G):

the mistake:

```
<application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
</application>
```

right:

```
<application
            android:name=".G" >
        ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it's not already mentioned, you may alternatively merge the files to stay in accordance with license requirements (or just use `pickFirst` as stated by Daniel Reina).

```
packagingOptions {
    merge "META-INF/LICENSE"
    merge "META-INF/AL2.0"
    merge "META-INF/LGPL2.1"
}
```

Reference: [Gradle API 4.2 Packaging Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions)

Comment: I guess that `merge` is more "legally safe" than `exclude` and `pickFirst` functions.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. i was getting the error message -

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'javax/annotation/WillCloseWhenClosed.java'
```

As stated in some of the answers above, using the below code works

```
'packagingOptions {
       exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
    }'
```

But i was getting this error for 20 different files, so after excluding 20 files, i stopped and tried to find a decent solution. I had also encountered the

```
'Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files' error.
```

I finally managed to solve this.

Firstly (as in my case WillCloseWhenClosed.java was the duplicate file), in android studio you have an option of 'search everywhere'. Write and search for the file there. There i found multiple instances of this file. So i clicked on both instances and saw their location by right clicking on the file and seeing its location when they opened in android studio.

Secondly, I figured out that i had some dependencies in gradle file. I was using the below code

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
}
```

and also i had their same zip packages in the location :\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\git\appname\app\libs\google-http-client-1.23!.

So this was redundant and thats why gradle is finding 2 files. So i deleted my zip packages and it solved the errors for me. Be carefull while doing this. You have to figure out which is the correct file or package to be deleted.

Thirdly, gradle also makes a zip of these bug files in this location (At least for me it made) - C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar!

so i went and deleted the jsr305-1.3.9.jar file from here also.

If you are still confused, just go the 'search everywhere' in android studio, find instances of your file there and you would have to delete one of them. Take your time and figure out which one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having same problem and I tried this

**Error:**
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'

**Solution:**

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me. Add these to your app's build.gradle within the android{} block.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put this inside the build.gradle (Module AppName)

```
android {
   // ....
   packagingOptions{
     pickFirst "androidsupportmultidexversion.txt"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in **gradle 7.2** and above you can fix the problem like this:

in your `app/build.gradle` in `android` block:

```
  packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/notice.txt")
        resources.merges.add("META-INF/LICENSE")
        resources.merges.add("META-INF/AL2.0")
        resources.merges.add("META-INF/LGPL2.1")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue when I updated **Gradle** to 7+ I just added inside the ***/app/build.gradle:***

```
android{
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue, first with some native libraries (.so files) and then with java/kotlin files. Turned out I was including a library from source as well as referencing artifactory through a transitive dependency. Check your dependency tree to see if there are any redundant entries. Use `./gradlew :app:dependencies` to get the dependency tree. Replace "app" with your module name if the main module name is different.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove multidex from default config and check the build error log.
If that log is some relatable with INotification class. Use this in android{}

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

This helps me.

Answer (score 1):

This is another syntax for Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
android {
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "META-INF/*"
            excludes += "anotherFile"
            excludes += "andSoOn..."
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In many of the answers on SO on this problem it has been suggested to add `exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'` and some other excludes. However none of these worked for me. In my case scenario was like this:

I had added this in dependancies:

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

And also I had added this in gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Both of these I had added, because I was getting build error 'cannot find symbol class Nullable' and it was suggested as solution to this on some of answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54043256/1911652)

However, eventually I landed up in getting error:

```
 More than one file was found with OS independent path 'androidsupportmultidexversion.txt'
```

No `exclude` was working for me. Finally I just removed those added lines above just out of suspecion (Solved 'cannot find symbol class Nullable' in some alternative way) and finally I got rid of this "More than one file was found with OS..." build error. I wasted hours of mine. But finally got rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem and you have a `gradle .jar dependency`, like this:

```
implementation group: 'org.mortbay.jetty', name: 'jetty', version: '6.1.26'
```

Interval versions until one matches and resolves the excepetion,and apply the best answer of this thread.`

Answer (score 0):

If you work with multi module project and face this issue while espresso testing, you need to add packagingOptions code each gradle file. In my case , I added below code for each gradle file.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/lib_release.kotlin_module'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `multiDexEnabled true` inside `android {}`

And remove `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:x.x.x'` from dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and simply fixed by changing `multidex` implementation

From

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

To

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin DSL in Kotlin Multiplatform go to `build.gradle.kts (:androidApp)`

```kotlin
android {
    packagingOptions.resources.excludes.add("paste-the-path-here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multi modular architecture, then try to add this in gradle files of all modules

```
android { ...
       packagingOptions {
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
       }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case code bellow worked,
In your

> app build.gradle

file add

```
android {    
    ..
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  '**'
    }
    ..
}
```