# On gradle:3.0.0 More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have updated my Android studio to 3.0 
and then he asked to upgrade to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`

everything went well until i decided to run my project and it's giving me this Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

My app gradle

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.demo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}'
```

My Library gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should add to application `build.gradle` your `packagingOptions`:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

Comment: i will give it a try

Comment: fixed, i had another error after "Unable to merge dex" i entered the multidex and it worked !

Comment: Hey ! I did multiDexEnabled true and     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2' but is still not working .. Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this first before you try other methods.

**first:**

check if you have set this in you **build.gradle->dependencies**

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

if you've set this in you build.gradle file then check for this too if you tried to import libraries from your libs directory:

```
implementation files('libs/...')
```

if you have this too in your build.gradle file, please remove it or comment it out, because you are trying to re-import the library again which result is that error.

Comment: Adding this "implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')" worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Simply adding below code solves the problem

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst  'META-INF/*'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the **packagingOptions** block with in the **android** block in your application **build.gradle**,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abcd.efgh.com.x"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 29
        versionName "1.9.2"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
```