# Build failed after adding google cloud storage dependency android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-platform, build.gradle, google-cloud-storage

I am added google cloud dependency by

```
implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.12.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
```

but my build is failed with the following error

```
Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now. The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor. Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
- auto-value-1.2.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2)
```

> I tried by disabling annotation processor

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/project.properties'
    }

.................
.........

javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
........................
```

I am getting following error

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'project.properties'
```

Comment: can you explain your Gradle build is online or offline

Comment: a Gradle build is online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this part as `dependencies`:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.1'
```

Comment: But I am not using auto value in my project.

Comment: Still, I am getting `More than one file was found with OS independent path 'project.properties'`

Comment: @RahulDevanavar it is a dependency of google cloud libraries. About the other error try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956341/on-gradle3-0-0-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf but itis some separate problem.You may wish to consider asking a separate question