# SendGrid API for Android using Java

Tags: java, android, email, android-gradle-plugin, sendgrid

Upon deep research, I was unable to integrate and send emails from SendGrid in the Android Application. SendGrid has Java API for sending emails but adding the dependency in Android Studio throws errors when a build is made. Also, there was a library by [Dany Santiyago in GitHub](https://github.com/danysantiago/sendgrid-android) but sadly it doesn't work too. It throws an error saying

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'

I followed the guidelines in the question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license) but again a new error came saying unable to merge dex. Please suggest a way to integrate SendGrid to the Android Application.

Comment: Please share the error/exception which you are getting and a snapshot of the build.gradle file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no perfect workaround as SendGrid doesn't have an Android API or SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on github : https://github.com/thinkingserious/sendgrid-android-example

The code is not production ready but I am using this in my Android app and it works fine. Leaving this here, for anyone for future reference.