# Example: Sending sendgrid email programmatically with Volley

Tags: java, android, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to send emails programmatically from Android through [sendgrid's v3 email API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html) with normal Java. While sendgrid has a Java library, it is not specific for Android and [more than 4y old](https://github.com/danysantiago/sendgrid-android).

Android suggests to use the [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) library for simple requests. However, I couldn't find any boilerplate code to start off with on how to send a simple request to sendgrid specifically. This would really make it much easier for me to get started - I haven't done any network requests from Android before.

This is the only related post I could find, but the suggested code example is terribly old, more than 6 years: [SendGrid API for Android using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780793/sendgrid-api-for-android-using-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new Android SendGrid library utilising Sendgrid's v3 API.

The update library negates many of the issues when implementing the older sendgrid libraries into applications that target newer Android API version.

The library can be imported with jitpack

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.2.3'
}
```

https://github.com/Jakebreen/android-sendgrid