# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'

Tags: android-workmanager

i am trying android [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/), The code is throwing error "**More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro**" when running, I tried the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license), it was not helpful.

[WorkManager Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#workmanager)

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rock.dmx.xaro.workmanagerexample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha09"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
}
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

This is a known problem at the moment, [Architecture Components Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes) outline the issue and provides a solution to fix it until `alpha10` version of work manager library:

> Known Issue
>
> If you run into the following issue: "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'", please put the following in your gradle file as a temporary workaround while we fix the issue in alpha10:

```
 android {
     packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
     }
 }
```

So, in your case, android section should be like following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rock.dmx.xaro.workmanagerexample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Temporary fix until alpha10
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}
```

Issue should be addressed properly in `1.0.0-alpha10` version of WorkManager.

Comment: In my case I had to add `exclude 'META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro'` to the packagingOptions also

Answer (score 13):

I got the same error when I added the following to my app's build.gradle dependencies section:

`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"`

#### Following the [Migration to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate):

1. In Android Studio, from the **Refactor** menu, select **Migrate
   to AndroidX...**
2. better check the option to **backup your project** as a zip file in case
   the migration fails,
3. and then after clicking **Migrate** you will get to choose the location
   to save the zip backup.

now I am able to build without problems so far.

---

#### My setup

> Android Studio 3.2.1
>  JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains
>  macOS 10.13.6

Answer (score 9):

Can use add in build.gradle(app) (answered by [TheStrikeBone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52523819/1770868))

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}
```

OR downgrade `android.arch.work` version into `1.0.0-alpha08`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha08'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding this to my apps build.gradle file solved my problem.

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more to understand? Thanks.

Comment: In addition， the packagingOptions must be added in the app module, not library module

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner, I had this issue while using a pre-made project for in some tutorial, and above solution didn't work for me.

So in case someone face same problem.

I had to upgrade gradle version in `build.gradle` file for project:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'        
    }
}
...
```

Then I had to upgrade gradle wrapper in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
#Wed Sep 26 11:30:41 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

# Delete this
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

# Add this
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Then, I set `useAndroidX` to true in `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

That's it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Upgrading my Gradle did the trick for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

In my case adding below code on build.gradle helps to solve the problem.

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst '**'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always look first for implementations in Gradle.
maybe two implementations collide with each other.. maybe you did not delete card view v7, and added androidx card view, something like that than you try other things.

I have just that situation and removing old implementation solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solve the problem by setting androidx.room use the same version as androidx.lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

```
android
{
    packagingOptions
    {
        exclude 'META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro'
    }
}
```