# How to fix 'cannot find symbol class Nullable' error in android studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i'm using android studio 3.2 , and want to use SQLiteOpenHelper in my blank class . when i have run project java compiler return error : cannot find symbol class Nullable

```
public class Db extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public Db(@androidx.annotation.Nullable Context context, @androidx.annotation.Nullable String name, @androidx.annotation.Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}}
```

I also used this implementation

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
```

I clicked Invalidate caches and restart on file menu and rebuild project but error still occurs

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

If you implement `com.android.support:support-annotations`, then you need to use `android.support.annoation.Nullable`.

It's a lot easier if you don't fully qualify the names, and just use `@Nullable` instead. Android Studio will then give you available imports.

If you are actually targeting API 24, like the implementation you list says you are, you simply can't use AndroidX. AndroidX requires a `targetSdkVersion` of 28 or higher.

Comment: Caution: It may cause build error going ahead. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642114/1911652)

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem adding

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in my `gradle.properties` file

Comment: Caution: It may cause build error going ahead. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642114/1911652)