# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' Problem

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHNMR.jpg]

There are say more than one file was found with os independent but i change all compile files version not run. I'm new in android studio so help me

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'})
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.0.5'
    implementation files('libs/apache-commons-httpmime.jar')
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license)

Comment: android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

Comment: but when i try to run then
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zznf

Answer (score 0):

You have to `exclude` (completely don't include any) or `pickFirst` (only one of those duplicated) inside your `packagingOptions`, e.g.

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        ...
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        // or use below
        // pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        ...
    }
}
```

See more details here: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Comment: but when i try to run then Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zznf –. Now whats can do