# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libRSSupport.so'

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting this error after including shimmer layout to my android project.

I tried editing my packagingOptions in my build.gradle (Module: app) but it did not work.

packagingOptions {

```
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```

Here is the xml code in my layout.

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmerUserProfileActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:shimmer_shape="radial"
    app:shimmer_duration="800"
    app:shimmer_auto_start="true"
    app:shimmer_repeat_mode="restart"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_shimmer_user_profile"/>

</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

The projects shows this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This worked.

```
android{
    packagingOptions{

        pickFirst 'lib/mips/libRSSupport.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libRSSupport.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/mips/librsjni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/librsjni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libRSSupport.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/librsjni.so'
    }
}
```

> This is the whole code for my packaging options.

```
android{
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

        pickFirst 'lib/mips/libRSSupport.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libRSSupport.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/mips/librsjni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/librsjni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libRSSupport.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/librsjni.so'

        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libsqlcipher.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libsqlcipher.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libsqlcipher.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libsqlcipher.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libsqlcipher.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libassmidi.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libassmidi.so'
    }
}
```

> I noticed that the problem was not really brought about by the shimmer layout. This is because the problem still persisted even after removing all the shimmer declarations, implementations and rebuilding my project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try this but:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libRSSupport.so'
     }
 }
```

I found something similar here:

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license)

Comment: Sure, Solves one of the errors that results after solving mine.