# Build failed android, deprecated features

Tags: java, android, exception, gradle

Was trying to get the MPAndroidCharts to work

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

  > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 46s

Comment: Hi. Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787905/1004631

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code in your application level build.gradle file.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify gradle to pick first (i.e. only one)

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}
```