# I am facing this error while building APK in react native

Tags: react-native, build, apk

[image: Image is attached]

I am building an APK of my react-native project, after this command ./gradlew assembleRelease I am encountering this error.

ERROR: > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease FAILED

I am expecting a genrated APK file, but did not succeeded.

Comment: Please copy error message as text.

Comment: Looks like you're including a library with .so files. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license

Answer (score 0):

watch below link,then check your react native version,go to react-native specific version search generate signed apk popup new screen,then create apk step-by-step,finally you are created apk.
https://youtu.be/cws_eQ5LQUk