# Android More than one file was found with OS independent path 'google/protobuf/type.proto'

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want add com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.1.1 to my project

After sync, I get below error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'google/protobuf/type.proto'
```

I use this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Also, I added this section:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/codec-http/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/common/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/transport/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/transport/reflection-config.json'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/buffer/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/handler/native-image.properties'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add the following code may help:

```
 exclude("google/protobuf/type.proto")
```

and you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license).