# Deeplearning4J nd4j-native.properties cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: android, deeplearning4j, dl4j

When I used DL4J(version 1.0.0-M1.1) on android studio, it says that "nd4j-native.properties cannot be opened because it does not exist".However if I used on IDEA or the version was 1.0.0-beta7, the error did not occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by including nd4j-native.properties as follows,

```
packagingOptions {
    merge 'nd4j-native.properties'
}
```

For **Gradle 7.0.2 and above** the following might work,

```
packagingOptions {
    resources.merges.add('nd4j-native.properties');
}
```

Also refer to [More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/LICENSE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify a bit about what you are running in to? Your build.gradle would be nice to see. It's kind of hard to tell what you might be running in to.

The only thing I can tell you is that there are certain properties files that are used by the framework that should be bundled in the jars.

Typically when this happens, that means that whatever is bundling the jar didn't include that resource.

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I had to exclude the file since the app was not building 
 due to the error "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'nd4j-native.properties'.". I am not sure as to how to build the app with the file excluded.