# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, duplicates, google-mobile-ads

We have a game developed in Unity. Recently i had to upgrade a plugin. Here is where the issues started, since Android now requires you know to upload apps targetting android 31.

Some details:

- Unity 2021.1.28f1
- Android sdk 31
- Gradle 6.1.1 (version Unity supports)

Multiple plugins

- Facebook (15.1.0)
- Firebase Analytics and Messaging (10.3.0)
- Google Mobile Ads Plugin (v7.3.1)
- TheoPlayer (a plugin to show advertisement specifcally for Belgium)
- ConsentManager

The issue lies with Google Mobile Ads and Theoplayer. TheoPlayer requires package **com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.22.2** this has a file named META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module and the **androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0@aar** used by Google mobile also has this file, so i constantly get the error when building **More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module'.**

Trying to exclude this file has no effect. I have no idea how to continue, googeling has not helped me neither. Anybody here with more android native coding experience who can help me further? I have attached our gradle file to this post.

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = path
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository" // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:22
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7, Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:12, Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:17, Assets/THEOplayer/Editor/THEOplayerDependencies.xml:13, Assets/THEOplayer/Editor/THEOplayerDependencies.xml:19
        }
        maven {
            url "path/ Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml:11
        }
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" // Assets/THEOplayer/Editor/THEOplayerDependencies.xml:7
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.0.0'
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha04' // Assets/ConsentManager/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0' // Assets/ConsentManager/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1' // Assets/ConsentManager/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies.xml:11
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.1' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:12
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' // Assets/ConsentManager/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies.xml:12
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[15.1,16)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[15.1,16)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[15.1,16)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[15.1,16)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[15.1,16)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.22.2' // Assets/THEOplayer/Editor/THEOplayerDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.1' // Assets/THEOplayer/Editor/THEOplayerDependencies.xml:19
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6' // Assets/ConsentManager/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:10.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:10.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.2.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:10.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01' // Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml:11
    implementation 'com.iabtcf:iabtcf-decoder:2.0.7' // Assets/ConsentManager/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies.xml:10
    implementation 'com.moat.analytics.mobile.mpub:moat-mobile-app-kit:+' // Assets/THEOplayer/Editor/THEOplayerDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
    implementation(name: 'billing-4.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-15.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'gameanalytics', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'googlemobileads-unity', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'instantapps-1.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'theoplayer-android-4.6.0-minapi21', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UniWebView', ext:'aar')
    implementation project('FirebaseApp.androidlib')
    implementation project('GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib')
    implementation project('GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib')
    implementation project('unity-android-resources')
}    

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/arm64-v8a/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.2.9'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.ress', '.resource', '.obb'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }
}
```

I have tried

- excluding one of the 2 packages makes the build succeed, but ofcourse i am missing libraries then so functionality is broken
- using different version of packages but no success
- tried upgrading to Unity 2022.2 but nothing works there anyway

I don't know why excluding doesn't work. Does this have to do with the location of the duplicate files being in External Libraries?

P.S. I have exported to android studio and fixing it in android studio. This error comes from within android studio environment.

[Hierarchy where the file is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGM8R.png)

Comment: You should be able to exclude the META-INF/* files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license

Comment: I still get the same error when i add the line exclude ("META-INF/*.kotlin_module"). The location of this file is in the external libraries, does this matter?

Comment: There are two different `packagingOptions {}` where you could add it. Did you try both?

Comment: Yes, no success.

Comment: Might try exporting an Android Studio project and building that. Kind of a grasping at straws option. :(

Comment: That is what i am doing. This error comes from out of my android studio project.

Comment: Ah, bummer. I suppose the nuclear option would be to unzip one of the aar files, delete the offending file, then zip it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search and some help from the Unity forums i was given this link:

https://socket.dev/npm/package/com.azerion.ads

At the bottom they actually talk about my specific error. Excluding the files is still the solution, but the key is to put the exclude command in the **launcher.gradle** file. Unity has an option to enable this. This then properly excludes the files even from external libraries. I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Forgot about the launcher. It's been a while since it has caused me grief. Glad you worked it out. :)